# Regex for matching a complete element in a xml file

Tags: regex

I would like to know the Regex that match these kind of sequences

```
<person name="the name I want" ....[other things]>
    .... [other tags]
</person>
```

I tried with something like this:

```
<person +name="the name I want" +.*
```

But I'm not going any further, I can only match the first line, but not the complete element

Would you like to help me?

Comment: Why regexp as compared to a proper xml-parser?

Comment: Have you tried?: <person +name="the name I want".+?(<\/person>)     as Fredrik said a parser might be a better alternative.

Comment: that regexp, at least with Notepad++, is not working. I didn't try with a proper xml-parser. What xml-parser do you recommend?

Comment: It does work here, have a look: http://regex101.com/r/iI6qP3

Comment: Do you NEED to do this, really? A solution like X-Path can't help you?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<person[*>]*name="the name I want"[^>]*>(.|[\r\n])*?<\/person>
```

If your language supports the "dotall" flag, you can use that and change `(.|[\r\n])*` to just `.*`.

Answer (score -1):

I found this in another stackoverflow thread:

```
<person(.|\r\n)*?<\/person>
```

I hope it is useful

Edit:

I forgot to add the name attribute

```
(<person name="the name I want"(.|\r\n)*?<\/person>)
```

Comment: this will match *every* person tag